# How to use jQuery to read from JSON?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to figure out how to work with the api from contentful.com. I've created a simple MVC5 app with the following view:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Contentful Index</h2>

<div id="pic">Pic should go here


</div>

@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        var client = contentful.createClient({
            accessToken: 'b4c0n73n7fu1',
            space: 'cfexampleapi'
        });

        var asset = client.asset('nyancat');

        $("#pic").css({ 'background-image': asset.fields.file.url });
    });
    </script>
}
```

When the page loads, I can see using fiddler that I get the following response from cdn.contentful.com:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 10 Mar 2014 16:54:17 GMT
Server: nginx/1.1.19
Content-Type: application/vnd.contentful.delivery.v1+json
X-Contentful-Request-Id: 85f-830919841
ETag: "7a92346b83c581d30e36cad903578c5a"
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept,Accept-Language,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Length,Content-Range,Content-Type,DNT,Destination,Expires,If-Match,If-Modified-Since,If-None-Match,Keep-Alive,Last-Modified,Origin,Pragma,Range,User-Agent,X-Http-Method-Override,X-Mx-ReqToken,X-Requested-With,X-Contentful-Version,X-Contentful-Content-Type,X-Contentful-Organization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,HEAD,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Content-Length: 724
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Via: 1.1 varnish
Age: 3578
X-Served-By: cache-lcy1120-LCY
X-Cache: HIT
X-Cache-Hits: 1
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Keep-Alive: timeout=10, max=50
Connection: Keep-Alive

{
  "fields": {
    "title": "Nyan Cat",
    "file": {
      "fileName": "Nyan_cat_250px_frame.png",
      "contentType": "image/png",
      "details": {
        "image": {
          "width": 250,
          "height": 250
        },
        "size": 12273
      },
      "url": "//images.contentful.com/cfexampleapi/4gp6taAwW4CmSgumq2ekUm/9da0cd1936871b8d72343e895a00d611/Nyan_cat_250px_frame.png"
    }
  },
  "sys": {
    "space": {
      "sys": {
        "type": "Link",
        "linkType": "Space",
        "id": "cfexampleapi"
      }
    },
    "type": "Asset",
    "id": "nyancat",
    "revision": 1,
    "createdAt": "2013-09-02T14:56:34.240Z",
    "updatedAt": "2013-09-02T14:56:34.240Z",
    "locale": "en-US"
  }
}
```

I then get the following error displayed in Chrome console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'file' of undefined.

I've tried `console.log(asset)` and it does tell me it's undefined. Could anyone please tell me where I went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.contentful.com/developers/documentation/content-delivery-api/), it seems the client.asset() function is asynchronous.  Try this:

```
var asset = client.asset('nyancat').then(function(asset){
    $("#pic").css({ 'background-image': asset.fields.file.url });
});
```